# Sublime Text 2 - compile a java code error

Tags: java, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I prepare my Sublime Text to compile a Java with tutorial http://www.compilr.org/compile-and-run-java-programs/ and when I hit ctrl+b, I get something like that:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'runJava.bat', u'C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\Test.java']]
[dir:  C:\Users\xx\Desktop]
[path: ?C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin]
[Finished]
```

It is `.bat` but it still doesn't work. My `JavaC.sublime-build` file is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["runJava.bat", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "encoding": "ISO-8859-2"
}
```

I'm on windows 8.

Comment: Can you please check your PATH variable, to see if you've added a `?` instead of a `;` before `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin` ?

Comment: Adding a `;` before PATH helps :) Thanks for help :)